# Laravel 5.1 - icon in the page title

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, page-title

I am struggling with adding an icon into the page title. So far I have tried adding it like this :

`<title> 
    <link rel="icon" href="{!! asset('images/gcm_ico.ico') !!}"/>@yield('page-title')
</title>`

But it gets escaped in all browsers as shown here :

[image]

I also tried printing the link with

```
{{ "<link rel='icon' hrer='".asset("images/gcm_ico.ico")."' />" }}.
```

Has anyone done this successfully? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure how it's actually escaped because the image does not show the part I need.

If you don't want the string to be escaped, you should use `{!! asset(...) !!}` instead.

Comment: @Satisfaction I have added a picture showing exactly what is being added to the title.

Comment: Are you adding your `<link/>` tag in the title? It most certainly should not appear in the title despite the problems you might be getting.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the exact piece of code from my main blade layout file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the favicon to the `<head></head>` part of the HTML document but not in the `<title>` itself.

Favicon is not really a part of title even if it appears so in the browser. You can check for more info on the favicon [here](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon).

The result should look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<title>@yield('page-title')</title>
<link rel="icon" href="{!! asset('images/gcm_ico.ico') !!}"/>
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Comment: This seemed to work.I don't know how I got the idea to add the icon in the <title> tag. Thanks for the help, highly appreciated

Comment: No problem! You should also into generating favicons for all browsers and platforms as you'll need multiple icons to be done if you want everything done 100%. Something like [this](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) will help you do all this.